# Custom statusText for JWT Token MVC Core

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, jwt, asp.net-core-middleware

I have implemented JWT Token authentication in my MVC Core Application using the following articles:

[Link 1](https://stormpath.com/blog/token-authentication-asp-net-core)

[Link 2](https://goblincoding.com/2016/07/03/issuing-and-authenticating-jwt-tokens-in-asp-net-core-webapi-part-i/)

This is what I have in my `Startup.cs`

```
    private const string SecretKey = "MySecretKey"; //TODO: remove hard coded get from environments as suggested in Blog
    private readonly SymmetricSecurityKey _signingKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(SecretKey));


    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {


        var jwtAppSettingOptions = Configuration.GetSection(nameof(JwtIssuerOptions));
        var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidIssuer = jwtAppSettingOptions[nameof(JwtIssuerOptions.Issuer)],

            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidAudience = jwtAppSettingOptions[nameof(JwtIssuerOptions.Audience)],

            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = _signingKey,

            RequireExpirationTime = true,
            ValidateLifetime = true,


            ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
        };

        app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions
        {
            AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
            AutomaticChallenge = true,
            TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters,

        });

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseBrowserLink();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");


            routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "areaRoute",
                    template: "{area:exists}/{controller}/{action}",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
                    );
        });

    }



    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add framework services.
        services.AddMvc(options => { });

        services.Configure<MvcOptions>(options => { });
        services.Configure<IISOptions>(options => { });

        services.AddOptions();


        #region Authentication and Authorisation

        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            using (var dbContext = new FoodHouseContext(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")))
            {
                var features = dbContext.Features.Select(s => s.Name).ToList();
                foreach (var feature in features)
                {
                    options.AddPolicy(feature, policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new FeatureRequirement(feature)));
                }
            }
        });

        // Configure JWT Token Settings
        var jwtAppSettingOptions = Configuration.GetSection(nameof(JwtIssuerOptions));

        services.Configure<JwtIssuerOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.Issuer = jwtAppSettingOptions[nameof(JwtIssuerOptions.Issuer)];
            options.Audience = jwtAppSettingOptions[nameof(JwtIssuerOptions.Audience)];
            options.SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(_signingKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
        });

        #endregion


    }
```

Everything is working fine - the Token is been issued and `Authorize` is working fine, when I make an UnAuthenticated request I get the following response:

[image]

As you can see the `Status = 401`, which means `UnAuthenticated` - But as you can see the StatusText is empty.

Now there are many reasons why the request can be UnAuthenticated e.g. `JWT Token expired` , what I want to do is pass a custom Status Text based on the Validation rule failing on the server, how can I do this in MVC Core?

Comment: As far as i know if jwt authentication fails, the server sends a response 401 status code and `Www-Authenticate` header like this: `Www-Authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The token is not valid yet"`.  Did you try to get `error_description` from header?

Comment: @ademcaglin you are right the error message is inside the header...